Drawing a diagonal line on top of a matrix
I need this:

I want to draw a line that goes through the diagonal and separates the matrix in two parts.

Have a look at the nicematrix package.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show something you tried. There are various possible approaches to this and it would be good to know which one suits your needs best. You added tikz-matrix as tag. Is this what you want to use?

With {pNiceMatrix} of nicmeatrix and TikZ to draw the line with the PDF/TikZ nodes created by nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  9 & 4 & 5 \\
  4 & 1 & 6 \\
  5 & 6 & 3
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \draw [red,dashed]  (1-|1) -- (last-|last) ; 
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}

As usual with nicematrix, you need several compilations.

It's also possible to put the line under the matrix by putting the instruction in the so-called \CodeBefore.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\CodeBefore
  \tikz \draw [red,dashed]  (1-|1) -- (last-|last) ; 
\Body
  9 & 4 & 5 \\
  4 & 1 & 6 \\
  5 & 6 & 3
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}



It would be preferable to draw the dotted line under the matrix.

@projetmbc: Good suggestion. I have modified my answer.

Quick-and-dirty solution with cancel package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{lightgray}}

\begin{document}
\[
\bcancel{\begin{pmatrix}9 & 4 & 5\\
4 & 2 & 6\\
5 & 6 & 3
\end{pmatrix}}
\]
\end{document}


A bit better solution in pure latex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(50,50)
{\color{gray} \multiput(8,22)(3,-2.7){15}{\line(1,-0.9){2}}}{2}}
\put(0,0){$ 
\begin{pmatrix}9 & 4 & 5\\
4 & 2 & 6\\
5 & 6 & 3
\end{pmatrix} 
$}
\end{picture}
\end{document}

I took the liberty of coloring the line gray; I hope it suits your purpose.

